# How to Find a Max and then see which column it is attributed to

Tags: excel, max

I am taking a max value between CD2 and CR2 using `=MAX(CD2:CR2)` and instead of going through manually to find which column holds the max, is there a way for it to return this value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [MATCH function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx).

For example, the following formula returns address of first entry of max value in range `CD2:CR2` (returns `$CF$2` for max in `CF2`):

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(CD2:CR2,1,MATCH(MAX(CD2:CR2),CD2:CR2,0)))
```

[image]

Alternatively you can return relative column number (starting from `CD`):

```
=MATCH(MAX(CD2:CR2),CD2:CR2,0)
```

i.e. formula returns `3` for above image - since `CF` - 3rd column from `CD`

For absolute column number:

```
=COLUMN($CD$2)+MATCH(MAX(CD2:CR2),CD2:CR2,0)-1
```

and [non-volatile](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm) version:

```
=COLUMNS($A$2:$CD$2)+MATCH(MAX(CD2:CR2),CD2:CR2,0)-1
```

both formulas return `84` for max in `CF2`.

Comment: Your answer is better than mine but it was missing the link I had, so I just put it in

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=MID(CELL("address",INDEX(CD2:CR2,1,MATCH(MAX(CD2:CR2),CD2:CR2,0))),2,2)
```